# For multi sign transaction, who will pay gas?

Tags: web3js

For multi sign transaction, who will pay for the gas? Any sample code? I am not quite sure about this.

Comment: based on implementation

Answer (score 0):

The first signer stores the transaction details by calling a designated function in the MultiSig contract, which returns a Transaction-ID.

This signer then gives the Transaction-ID to each one of the other signers, and each one of them approves the transaction by passing that Transaction-ID to a another designated function in the MultiSig contract.

When the last required signer (for example, the 5th signer, when 5 out of 8 authorized signers are required) approves the transaction, it is being executed.

So each one of the signers pays a certain amount, and the last one also pays for the actual transaction to be executed (typically, this means that each signer pays a small fee, and the last signer pays a much larger fee).

Comment: so each signer must pay more than 0 at least?

Comment: @Louis: Yes, of course. Every transaction must be paid for (as I have already explained in several other questions of yours).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard for multisig wallets so different implementations can have different mechanism to pay for transaction execution.

- https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet: each signer pays a little to approve the proposed transaction and the last one to sign will pay for the execution.
- https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig: signatures are made off-chain so a single person will pay for everything. For example in the case of ether transfer the recipient can collect the signatures and pay the transaction fee by himself.